# When to use in-place layers in Caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, backpropagation

By setting the bottom and the top blob to be the same we can tell Caffe to do "in-place" computation to preserve memory consumption.

Currently I know I can safely use in-place `"BatchNorm"`, `"Scale"` and `"ReLU"` layers (please let me know if I'm wrong). While it seems to have some issues for other layers ([this issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2015) seems to be an example).

When to use in-place layers in Caffe?
How does it work with back-propagation?

Comment: @Shai thanks for the answer, it surely helps!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you well noted, in-place layers don't usually work "out of the box".
For some layers, it is quite trivial (`"ReLU"` and other neuron activation layers).
However, for others it requires special handling in code. For example, the implementation of [`"PReLU"`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/prelu_layer.cpp#L102-L121) layer has specific cache `bottom_memory_` member variable that stores information needed for backprop.
You can see similar code for other layers that specifically test for `if (top[0] == bottom[0])` to see if the layer is used in an "in-place" case.

Moreover, it makes little sense to have an in-place layer for which the input and output are of different shapes, thus layers such as `"Convolution"`, `"InnerProduct"`, `"Pool"` are not considered as candidates for "in-place" layers.

Comment: Thanks. How about `in-place=True` and `in-place=False` for BatchNorm layer? Sometimes, I saw the papers `in-place=False` for the BatchNorm layer. Do we have any benefit for that case?

Comment: @user8264 I'm not very familiar with the internal of BatchNorm layer so I can't really comment about it. Sometimes using in place requires a bit more computation (for saving up space)... you'd really need to ask the person who specified `in_place=False`...