# How many bottoms/tops a layer can have in caffe structure

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

i keep seeing some layers in caffe that has two bottoms(source) or tops(destination) in Neural networks architecture,for example this is [Segnet](https://github.com/alexgkendall/SegNet-Tutorial/blob/master/Models/segnet_train.prototxt) data layer that has two tops ,data and label given from the same source file on the same line img1.png lagel1.png

```
    layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  dense_image_data_param {
    source: "train.txt" # train file format img1.png img1.png (data and label)
    batch_size: 1               
    shuffle: true
  }
```

and these from [Pascal-object-detection-fc](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/finetune_pascal_detection/pascal_finetune_trainval_test.prototxt)

```
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc8_pascal"
  bottom: "label"
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "fc8_pascal"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
```

that have two bottoms.

I would appreciate if someone could explain  the implication of having those into one layer and why not have different layer for each.
Another thing,if a layer reference its self as top/bottom,does it mean it does not do forward/backward calculations?

Comment: what do you mean by "if a layer reference its self as top/bottom"??

Comment: in the example i gave...accuracy layer has top: accuracy, it kind of confuses me it is point it as the one processing data from its own bottom or just to say that is the top of fc8_pascal?

Comment: `"bottom"` and `"top"` are names of data blobs processed by the net. You should **not** confuse their names with the layer's `"name"`. Layer's `"name"` is used to reference internal layer's parameters (if any). These parameters are **different** than processed data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of a layer as a mathematical operation: each layer type performs different operation. `"Convolution"` layer convolves the input with the layer's internal parameters, `"ReLU"` performs linear rectification etc.
Some operations do not require any inputs (`"bottom"`s): these are usually input layers that brings data/labels into the net.
Other layers only act on a single operand (one `"bottom"`) and outputs a single result (one `"top"`): `"Convolution"`, `"ReLU"`, `"Softmax"` just to name a few.
Other layers may produce several outputs (many `"top"`s), e.g., `"Slice"` layer.
And you can also find layers that takes several inputs and produce a single output, e.g., `"Eltwise"` layer.

Bottom line, each layer/operation requires a different number of inputs and may produce a different number of outputs. You should not confuse between input/output blobs and the layer's operation.

For more information about caffe's layers you can find at [caffe.help](http://caffe.help/manual/layers.html).

Comment: thank you very much for your clarification...if a layer references itself(name:loss", top:loss") does it means that it has no other layer to foward to?

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan it only means the layer's name is the same as a blobs name. no biggie. **If** you see the same `"bottom"` and `"top"` name of the same layer, then you are looking at an ["in-place" layer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38474899/1714410).

Comment: ah....thank you very much...i think the in-place layer were the one confusing me...i didnt cross them before

Comment: ...one last question...if a layer use another name for top/bottom that has the name of another layer...is it referencing to that layer`s blob?

Comment: do not confuse layer names and blob names. they are two *separate* things.

Comment: @Shai...i understand....so far to what was related to my question....just doing some confirmation...that blob are independent of layers....such as blob : label is accessed by loss layer even if it was defined in input layer?

Comment: the `"labe"` blob is the `"top"` of `"input"` layer - that is `"input"` layer "generates" label information. Then `"loss"` layer uses `"label"` blob as an input it requires to compute the loss.